# Global overload of operator<< does not work, why?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have learnt the ***operator<<*** can be overloaded by making it a friend function of class.
For example,

```
struct Test
{
    std::string d_data;
    Test(const std::string & data) : d_data{data} {}
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & ostr, const Test & obj)
    {
        ostr << obj.d_data << '\n';
        return ostr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t1("one");
    std::cout << t1;
    Test t2("two");
    std::cout << t2;
}
```

> ```
> one
> two
> ```

This seems to work as expected.

But, I'm unable to understand why the same isn't working for a global overload.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const std::string & s)
{
    os << s << '\n';
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "stackoverflow";
    std::cout << "stackoverflow";
}
```

> `stackoverflowstackoverflow`

Expected the strings to be separated by a newline, but didn't work as expected.

Comment: Your first example, which you claim work, should not work at all as you show it. The overloaded `operator<<` function you show doesn't access the object being passed (`tObj`) so the symbol `d_data` is unknown. It shouldn't build. When creating a [mcve], please make sure it actually replicates the behavior you specify.

Comment: You're not allowed to do that. None of the types in your operator are yours, so that operator is not yours to define.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your operator using

```
std::cout << "stackoverflow";
```

requires a user-defined conversion from an object of the type `const char *` (after the implicit conversion of the string literal to pointer to its first character) to an object of the type `std::string`.

However the standard basic_ostream class has already an operator that does not require such a conversion

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&, const char*);
```

So this operator is called instead of your operator.

Moreover within your operator

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const std::string & s)
{
    os << s << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

there is recursive calls of itself.

Your could define your operator the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const char *s)
{
    return std::operator <<( os, s ) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "stackoverflow";
    std::cout << "stackoverflow";
}
```

and get the expected result

```
stackoverflow
stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that `"stackoverflow"` is of type `const char[]`, but not `std::string`. That means your overload won't be invoked, but the one from standard library ([`operator<<(std::basic_ostream)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is invoked, because it's an exact match and doesn't require the implicit conversion from `const char[]` to `std::string`.

> ```
> template< class Traits >
> basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,  
>                                         const char* s );
> ```

<sup>BTW: It could be found because of [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).</sup>

Comment: @uneven_mark I realized it doesn't quite match OP's case. Modification of std namespace is UB, but OP doesn't modify it in fact. And, providing overloading on custom types should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload globally, but `"stackoverflow"` is not a `std::string`, so yours isn't used.
(And there already is such an overload in the standard library.)

To see that it works, move your first overload out of the class definition and make it a non-friend.
The only reason it has to be declared `friend` is that you have declared it inside the class definition, so it would be a member function otherwise.

This will work as you expect:

```
struct Test
{
    std::string d_data;
    Test(const std::string & data) : d_data{data} {}
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & ostr, const Test & obj)
{
    ostr << obj.d_data << '\n';
    return ostr;
}

int main()
{
    Test t1("one");
    std::cout << t1;
    Test t2("two");
    std::cout << t2;
}
```